# Change primary language for an App in the AppStore

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I need to change the primary language from Spanish (Spain) to English (U.S.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly change the primary language. You first have to get your app approved with the desired language set as an additional language.

This is from [Apple's documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve6f78a8e2?sub=devb34f436a9):

> You can change the primary language for an app. In order for a
>   language to be selectable as a primary language:
>
> You must already have added the language to a previous version.
>
> The new language must be approved by App Review. If the language has
>   not been approved, submit a version with this localized metadata to be
>   approved. Then, select it as your primary language on a subsequent
>   update.
>
> You must already have uploaded screenshots for that language that were
>   approved by App Review. If the screenshots for that localization are
>   being derived from another localization’s screenshots, you must first
>   manually add screenshots for that language and submit a version with
>   these screenshots to be approved. Then, select it as your primary
>   language on a subsequent update.
>
> 1.From the homepage, click My Apps, then select the app.
>
> 2.From the Primary Language pop-up menu, choose the new primary language.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: The problem was that the languages were approved previously but the screenshots didn't have any text since it was a calculator app. Now I added some artwork to the screenshots and some texts in each language and the Combobox was enabled a version later

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the languages approved by Apple. Only then you can change the primary language if it is no the first submission. So fill out all required information and submit the languages/version for review. Once it's approved, the dropdown will get active and you can change the primary language.

Comment: What do you mean with approving the languages? Sending an app version with that version as an alternative and being approved? Or I have to do something specifically? 

About the dropdown, is currently active, but when I click on one of the options I see the description, keywords and all info in that language but there's no button to choose as primary language

Comment: You'll need to send the app version with the languages active for review. Only if the language is approved, you can change the primary language to that new language.

Comment: How can I know that the languages were approved? Because the new app version was approved?

Comment: @VictorRius Yes, Apple always reviews all information: the build, metadata, screenshots etc. Once the version is approved, all (new) languages are approved and you can change the primary language.

Comment: Hi Max, It was approved. But I can't find how to change the primary language. Could you please add screenshots to your answer?